# java: make Apache HttpClient connect to host with specific IP

Tags: java, apache, http

Some domain names are resolved to several IPs by DNS. I need to make http requests to all those IPs (a kind of service healthcheck). I can use

```
InetAddress[] addrs = InetAddress.getAllByName("google.com")
```

to resolve all IPs which should be checked. *It is not about google, but it is with testing on google that I've found puzzles*

I'm trying to use Apache HttpClient to make request. Like this:

```
HttpHead req = new HttpHead(url);
//InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress("google.com", new byte[] {74, 125, (byte) 131, 101});
InetAddress addr = // one of those we got from InetAddress.getAll...
CloseableHttpResponse resp = cli.execute(new HttpHost(addr, 443, "https"), req);
```

It seems to work, however I decided to check it constructing the IP manually - see the commented string. If it is uncommented and used instead
of the `addr` from the dns enumeration, all works fine, returning 200.

But if I then change IP address to `8, 8, 8, 8` in this line and expect
to get connection timeout (as it is address of google's dns which don't
listen on 443 port, it is firewalled) - I see 404 instead. Thus I am not sure it uses the specified IP for real connection rather than for verification.

This makes me think that the approach is wrong and I use this HttpHost incorrectly.

**Alternative approach** is to use custom `DnsResolver` set up for given
`HttpClient`, which will feed only specific IPs, and do it in turns. however this looks like ugly and inconvenient hack so I'm searching for "proper" way...

P.S. variant with sending requests in plain text to sockets (without any library) will work fine, but most probably solution will need to work with `https` also
which makes this variant difficult.

Comment: A 404 is indeed a strange response. But you post only a part of the code, it shouldn't be too difficult to create a proper [mcve].

Comment: I thought of this, but as the library is involved, minimal example will be really a collection of files in form of gradle project, and here it stops being really minimal. I rather expected that someone well acquainted with this library will exclaim "dude, this is completely wrong usage of API" :)

Comment: Well at least a more complete code snippet you're basing your test on and not some broken half-commented snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to hit a specific IP is correct and works:

```
try {
    HttpClient hc = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet req = new HttpGet("https://www.google.com");
    HttpResponse res = hc.execute(new HttpHost("8.8.8.8", 443, "https"), req);
    System.out.println(res.getStatusLine());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Prints:

`Certificate for <8.8.8.8> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.c.docs.google.com, .....`

Apparently the [Google's Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) server `8.8.8.8` in addition to DNS also listens on port 443:

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 8.8.8.8:443 | more
CONNECTED(0000012C)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=*.c.docs.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
```

Now I can't speak intelligently about the content it is serving, but I can conclude that `8.8.8.8` isn't meant to handle `https://www.google.com` traffic since neither `*.c.docs.google.com` nor any of the subject alternative names match `www.google.com`.

Comment: Oh, well... Thanks for cross-checking this and finding my fault. It seems I have initially used 8.8.8.8 in tests with port 80 (which it seems not being listening) and then mistakenly changed it to 443 at some point - and you are right, `telnet 8.8.8.8 443` easily shows this port could be open...